# RSpec test index view and will_paginate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot, will-paginate

I'm new in test with Ruby and I use [Rspec](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails) & [FactoryGirl](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl_rails) for that.

I want to test my index view which obviously has a `will_paginate` in it.

Here is my controller :

```
def index
  @products = Product.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page=>30)
  respond_with(@products)
end
```

I have a basic view with `will_paginate` and a table of products.

Here is my test :

```
RSpec.describe "products/index", type: :view do
  before(:each) do
    @products = Array.new
    31.times do
      @products << FactoryGirl.create(:product)
    end
    assign(:products, @products)
  end

  it "renders a list of products" do
    render
  end
end
```

First of all, is it the right way to do it: Create an Array, then assigning it ?

Correct me if I'm wrong but `assign(:products, @products)` is the equivalent of `@products = Product.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page=>30)` **for test** ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I bypassed my issue with this code :

```
RSpec.describe "products/index", type: :view do
  before(:each) do
    # Create a list of 31 products with FactoryGirl
    assign(:products, create_list(:product, 31))
  end

  it "renders a list of products" do
    allow(view).to receive_messages(:will_paginate => nil)
    render
  end
end
```

I'm open to any suggestion about this solution.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not the same. Because an array is different from an ActiveRecord::Relation with [Relation methods](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/blob/master/lib/will_paginate/active_record.rb) (this is what `Product.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page=>30)` returns).
Maybe is a better way, but this should work:

```
RSpec.describe "products/index", type: :view do
  before(:each) do
    @products = WillPaginate::Collection.new(4,10,0)
    31.times do
      @products << FactoryGirl.create(:product)
    end
    assign(:products, @products)
  end

  it "renders a list of products" do
    render
  end
end
```

Here `@products = WillPaginate::Collection.new(4,10,0)` creates a collection with 4 page and 10 elements on each page.